# Como verificar e imprimir valores que se repetem em um vetor

Tags: array, c++

estou com o seguinte problema para verificar os vetores que se repetem em um Vetor:

Dada uma sequência de n números  reais,  determinar  os  números  que compõem a sequência e o número de vezes que cada um deles ocorre na mesma.

Exemplo:

n = 8

Sequência:

-1.7, 3.0, 0.0, 1.5, 0.0, -1.7, 2.3, -1,7

Saída:

-1.7 ocorre 3 vezes

3.0 ocorre 1 vez

0.0 ocorre 2 vezes

1.5 ocorre 1 vez

2.3 ocorre 1 vez

eis o código que escrevi ate aqui em C++:

```html
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main () {
 int n, i, i2, i3, a, cont=0;
 cin>>n;
 float vet[n], vet2[n], vet3[n];
 for(i=0 ; i<n ; i++){
  cin>>vet[i];
  vet2[i]=vet[i];
 }
 for(i=0 ; i<n ; i++){
  cont=0;
  for(i2=0 ; i2<n ; i2++){
   if(vet[i]==vet2[i2]){
    cont++;
    vet3[i]=vet[i];
   }
  }
  cout.precision(1);
  cout<<fixed<<vet[i]<<" ocorre "<<cont<<" vezes"<<endl;  
 }
   
 
 return 0;
}
```

Ate o momento estou tendo o seguinte resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o problema e que os valores repetidos estão sendo mostrado na quantidade de vezes que contem dentro do vetor, e não apenas uma como pede o exercício.

:/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Colega, eu já não programo pra C há algum tempo, mas fiz o que você precisa em javascript, a lógica é a mesma

```js
var array = [1,2,3,2,4,5,6,3,6,8,7,4]
var arrayVerificado = [];

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
 var contador = 0;  
  var repetiu = false;
  
  for(var z = 0; z < arrayVerificado.length; z++){
   if(arrayVerificado[z] == array[i]){
     //Verifico se no array auxiliar, o número já foi verificado, caso sim, seto a variavel repetiu para true.
     repetiu = true
    }
  }  
  if(repetiu == false){ //caso não tenha repetido, eu deixo o padrão false.
  arrayVerificado.push(array[i])//add no meu array auxiliar que este número vai ser verificado
    for(var j = 0; j < array.length; j++){
      if(array[i] == array[j]){ //se ele achar, faço meu contador acrescentar +1
        contador++
      }
      
    }
      console.log("O número: "+ array[i]+ " repetiu: "+ contador + " vezes");
      }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que você está atribuindo um valor 8 pra N, digamos que seu vetor:

```
vet[0] = -1.7
vet[1] = 3
vet[2] = 0
vet[3] = 1.5
vet[4] = 0
vet[5] = -1.7
vet[6] = 2.3
vet[7] = -1.7
```

Entã toda vez ele irá verificar, pois no seu for ele irá percorrer esse vetor as 8 vezes, por exemplo no seu caso na posição 0 5 e 7 do seu vetor, temos o valor -1.7, logo quando cair no segundo `for` ele fará essa verificação nas posições 0, 5 e 7. Observe tambem que seu comando para imprimir `cout` está logo após que o segundo comando de repetição termina e antes que o primeiro irá começar novamente, então ele irá imprimir todas as 8 vezes.

Answer (score -1):

Existe um "Jeito C++ que não é C" de fazer algumas coisas, sempre que vc puder usar C++ prefira :

1 - Use containers stl : std::vector no lugar de vetores "float vet[n]", pois a alocação e desalocação são automáticas.

2 - Use std::map para valores que devem ser "indexados" por chaves de pesquisa

```
vector<float> vet;
map<float, int> result;
```

3 - Use algoritmos e iteradores da stl no lugar de "for ( int.." pq fica clara a sua intenção ) std::copy, std::transform, std::find... por exemplo para copiar n elementos de uma entrada use std::copy_n( in... ), para inserir num vetor, use std::back_inserter :

```
copy_n(istream_iterator<float>(in), n, back_inserter(vet));  // le n elementos float de in e insere no vetor.
```

4 - Mapas são estruturas nativas de pesquisa: A linha a baixo tem 2 comandos: um é `result[v]` que pesquisa v em result, caso não encontre cria um default `int()` (inicializado com 0) no mapa com a chave 'v' que vc usou pra pesquisar e retorna uma referencia pare ele, caso encontre retorna uma referencia para o item encontrado, de qualquer forma, o mapa garante que existirá uma referência válida na resposta. A outra parte é `++` que será executado no resultado da primeira parte. Somando perfeitamente 1 no item que vc procura.

```
++result[v]
```

5 - Pra gerar o resultado o for padrão de mapas :

```
 for( const auto& [k, v] : result) {
   cout << k << " -> " << v << endl;
 }
```

Exemplo no compiler explorer
https://godbolt.org/z/MzPcc1